# Local variables in java bytecode

Tags: java, bytecode

I am trying to learn java bytecode and I stumbled on this:
I compiled this very simple code with the `-g` option:

```
public class Test
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  double a = 1.0;
  int b = (int)a;
 }
}
```

The main code turned out to be:

```
0 dconst_1
1 dstore_1
2 dload_1
3 d2i
4 istore_3
5 return
```

In addition, main's maximum local variables is 4, and the LocalVariableTable has only 3 entries (args, a, b). I am curious to know why the compiler reserved 4 local variables while there is clearly only 3, and `localvariable[2]` is not used. Is there something I'm missing? Thank you

Answer (score 25, accepted):

it is 4 because long and double occupies 2 consecutive entries in the frame. This is clearly specified by the [Java JVM specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#17257):

> A value of type long or type double
>   occupies two consecutive local
>   variables. Such a value may only be
>   addressed using the lesser index. For
>   example, a value of type double stored
>   in the local variable array at index n
>   actually occupies the local variables
>   with indices n and n +1; however, the
>   local variable at index n +1 cannot be
>   loaded from. It can be stored into.
>   However, doing so invalidates the
>   contents of local variable n.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know Java bytecode, this is just a guess:

Could it have to do with the fact that `a` is a `double`? Are two words being reserved for it?